# identify div inside (this) to show with jquery

Tags: jquery, mouseover, show

http://s199881165.onlinehome.us/transfem/newlayout/indexlisttrypopupquestion.php

Above is a page that i am working on. You will find that if you mouseover the tiles in the timeline a bunch of divs pop up that are placed below each tile.

However I would like only THE ONE CORRESPONDING div to appear for each tile.

```
 $('#sortable1 li').mouseenter(function()
    {

          $( '.infofloat').show( "scale", 300 );


      });

      $('#sortable1 li').mouseleave(function()
    {
          $( '.infofloat').hide( "scale", 300 );
    });
```

and the html

```
<div class="timelinehouse_div" id="theone<? echo $nummy;?>"><div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(<? echo $piccy;?>);"></div>
 <div class="meta"><div class='coverup'></div><? echo $tittie; ?></div></div>
  <div class="infofloat"><div class='arrowtop'></div></div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$(this)` to target current `li` and use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get your corresponding `.infofloat` child div

```
$('#sortable1 li').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find( '.infofloat').show( "scale", 300 );
});

$('#sortable1 li').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find( '.infofloat').hide( "scale", 300 );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using context, you can target only the `.infofloat` inside the list item :

```
$('#sortable1 li').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
          $( '.infofloat', this).show( "scale", 300 );
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
          $( '.infofloat', this).hide( "scale", 300 );
    }
});
```

Just for fun, a shorter version would be:

```
$('#sortable1 li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $( '.infofloat', this)[e.type=='mouseenter'?'show':'hide']( "scale", 300 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `find()` method:

```
$(this).find('.infofloat').show( "scale", 300 );
```